# Edit a json object from php

Tags: php, json

I read a json in this way

```
$app = json_decode($dati);
foreach($app->ambient as $mydata){
    foreach($mydata->layer as $mydata2){
         foreach($mydata2->layer_obj as $mydata3){
             if($mydata3->obj == "ipcam"){   

             }
         }
    }
}
```

when I'm inside the **if** i should be able to change some variable of the object, I have tried in various ways, without success

The object $mydata3 is something like that

```
{
  obj: "ipcam",
  indirizzo_locale: {
       ip: "0.0.0.0",
       port: "80",
       url: "/test",
       username: "admin",
       password: "admin"
  },
  indirizzo_remoto: {
      ip: "0.0.0.0",
      port: "80",
      url: "/test",
      username: "admin",
      password: "admin"
  }
}
```

Comment: json_decode... change the array / object.. then json_encode it again?

Comment: **How** did you try to change the **property**? Pass the properties by reference in the foreach and just set it like `$mydata3->obj->property = 'new';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to make changes to the object you are iterating, you will need to access the members by reference, using the `&` symbol:

```
foreach($app->ambient as &$mydata){
    foreach($mydata->layer as &$mydata2){
         foreach($mydata2->layer_obj as &$mydata3){
             if($mydata3->obj == "ipcam"){
                 $mydata3->indirizzo_locale->ip = 'you changed the ip';
             }
         }
    }
}

var_dump($app);
```

Comment: I've updated the question .. I should be able to modify (for example) indirizzo_locale-> ip

Comment: @WhiteLine Then change that property - I updated my answer to illustrate

Comment: ok the problem was when I returned the new json changed. I returned $dati and not json_encode($app), thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$app = json_decode($dati);
foreach($app->ambient as &$mydata){
    foreach($mydata->layer as &$mydata2){
         foreach($mydata2->layer_obj as &$mydata3){
             if($mydata3->obj == "ipcam"){   

             }
         }
    }
}
```

The variables are called by reference, which means when editing a variable like $mydata3, you also alter $app.

Otherwise you only change a copy of small parts of $app, which will not be part of $app.

Answer (score 0):

when using json_decode( json_encoded_object ), it returns object,

if you want to get result in array pass second argument 'true' in json_decode() function.

like this : json_decode( json_encoded_object, true );